# Compare two software version number using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

How to find latest version number using Regex ? 
 for example

3.0.0.0  &  3.1.0.0

4.0.1.0  &  4.0.1.2

**regards**

anbu

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Split the version string at the dots, convert the parts to integeres, and compare them one-by-one (start with the major version).

Answer (score 12):

Why use regular expressions? They don't perform comparisons. However, [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) not only will parse strings, but it supports comparisons:

```
// Use your favorite comparison operator
var current = new Version("4.0.1.2");
var found = new Version("4.0.1.0");
if (found > current)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upgrade needed to {0} from {1}", found, current);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No upgraded needed from {0}", current);
}
```

Or if you have them in an enumeration, it works nicely with LINQ:

```
var versions = new [] { "3.0.0.0", "3.1.0.0", "4.0.1.0", "4.0.1.2" };
foreach (var version in versions.Select(Version.Parse)
                                .OrderByDescending(v => v))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", version);
}

// Group them by Major Version first, then sort
foreach (var major in versions.Select(Version.Parse)
                              .GroupBy(v => v.Major)
                              .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",
                      major.Key,
                      String.Join(", ", major.OrderByDescending(v => v)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
static class Program

{

static void Main()

{

string v1 = "1.23.56.1487";
string v2 = "1.24.55.487";

var version1 = new Version(v1);
var version2 = new Version(v2);

 var result = version1.CompareTo(version2);
    if (result > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("version1 is greater");
    else if (result < 0)
        Console.WriteLine("version2 is greater");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("versions are equal");
    return;

}
```

}

Answer (score -4):

Well version number is just a number.. comparing 3.0.0.0 & 3.1.0.0 is just as comparing 3000 and 3100 the easiest is:

```
int v1 = 3000;
int v2 = 3100;

if (v2 > v1) { my routine; }
```

Comment: Except if the version is `4.0.30319.1` (the current C# compiler's version number).

Comment: You DID NOT mention comparing different versions with the SAME major release number!!!!!!